# Wheel ab workout equipment

Tags: workout, abdominals, exercise-equipment

I am considering buying an ab wheel. Will exercising with it make my abs look stronger and more apparent?

I'm not sure if an ab wheel will have a substantial effect on my abs in a short time. Lower and up abs I think will blow up.

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that you can get most of the benefits of an ab wheel with a cheap towel and a smooth floor.

Comment: @SeanDuggan But then you can pick up an ab wheel in the January sales for about £5, and can use it on carpet :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ab wheels are a great tool, but unfortunately, that alone won't give you visible abs.

The bottom line is that no matter how well-shaped your abs are, they won't be visible unless you burn the fat that covers them.

In other words, I do recommend ab wheels. I love them. But the *real* way to get visible and toned abs, is to get your diet in order. Both these things combined will have the effect you desire.

Since this is a very commonly asked question, I'll refer you to some similar questions with decent answers.

[What can I do to make my abs look their best in a very short timeframe?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/1972/what-can-i-do-to-make-my-abs-look-their-best-in-a-very-short-timeframe?rq=1)

[What are ways to exercise abdominal muscles without harming your back?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/14082/what-are-ways-to-exercise-abdominal-muscles-without-harming-your-back?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[What exercises should I perform to reduce fat on a specific area of my body?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/869/what-exercises-should-i-perform-to-reduce-fat-on-a-specific-area-of-my-body/870#870)

[How to lose fat fast and healthily?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/13255/how-to-lose-fat-fast-and-healthily/13256#13256)

[Optimal exercises for an abdominal workout](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/3354/optimal-exercises-for-an-abdominal-workout/3372#3372)